# How to convert only special characters to html entities without escaping <, >, " and '?

Tags: java, html, encoding, java-8, html-entities

I need to escape special characters in mail to html5 entities, because, even if the mail is sent as utf8, some client mails does not display them correctly. I don't want to use entities directly in the mail, since the mail are made by testers and we don't want to enforce testers to learn all html5 entities.

I tried to use

```
org.unbescape.html.HtmlEscape.escapeHtml​(
    string, 
    HtmlEscapeType.HTML5_NAMED_REFERENCES_DEFAULT_TO_DECIMAL,
    HtmlEscapeLevel.LEVEL_2_ALL_NON_ASCII_PLUS_MARKUP_SIGNIFICANT
)
```

[link](https://www.unbescape.org/apidocs/unbescape/1.1.6.RELEASE/org/unbescape/html/HtmlEscape.html#escapeHtml-java.lang.String-org.unbescape.html.HtmlEscapeType-org.unbescape.html.HtmlEscapeLevel-)

but they both escape also `<`, `>`, `"` and `'` characters.

Now I'm using this self-made method:

```
public static final String encodeHTML(final String s) {
    String res = HtmlEscape.escapeHtml(
        s, 
        HtmlEscapeType.HTML5_NAMED_REFERENCES_DEFAULT_TO_DECIMAL,
        HtmlEscapeLevel.LEVEL_2_ALL_NON_ASCII_PLUS_MARKUP_SIGNIFICANT
    );

    res = res.replaceAll("&lt;", "<");
    res = res.replaceAll("&gt;", ">");
    res = res.replaceAll("&quot;", "\"");
    res = res.replaceAll("&apos;", "'");
    res = res.replaceAll("&amp;", "&");

    return res;
}
```

Example:

```
encodeHTML("<div id='a' class\"ciao\">&amp; ®</div>")
```

outputs:

```
<div id='a' class"ciao">&amp; &reg;</div>
```

That's what I want, but there's not something more standard?

Comment: In what context do you want to escape into HTML entities but not escape HTML reserved characters?

Comment: I need to send a mail text that can be html. Since who writes the mail don't want to bother with special characters, I need a function that encodes only special characters.

Comment: Thing is, `>`, `<` etc. *are* special characters when they are in HTML. That is, if you are now going to put the converted text inside `<BODY>` tags, and it contains something like "Dear Dan, I want you to avoid using <PRE> when you write HTML pages", your mail will actually see that `<PRE>` and interpret it as HTML. So you *have* to escape them. But do so **before you embed the text in HTML**.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I updated the question with an example, so my goal now it's more clear.

Comment: Your example makes it clear that you are encoding it **too late**. You should always encode the text **before you embed it into HTML**. When you have already done this mistake, there is no canonical way to solve it and you are susceptible to HTML injection.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Mails are not written by devs, but by testers. They know just a little of html, we don't want to force them to learn all HTML entities. If you don't want to solve my problem, please do not reply, thanks.

Comment: The main problem is the wrong assumption that you need to encode characters at all. If you embed HTML in a mail correctly, you can keep using an encoding that supports all characters, like UTF-8, as used by more than 99% of the world. There is no need to replace `®` with `&reg;`.

Comment: @Holger: we send mails in UTF-8, but some mail clients, as outlook, ignores them. So this trick.

Comment: @Holger: I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Following code help you to convert only special characters.

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.AggregateTranslator;
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.EntityArrays;
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.LookupTranslator;

public String encodeHTML(String s) {

    StringEscapeUtils.Builder buider =StringEscapeUtils
        .builder(new AggregateTranslator(new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.ISO8859_1_ESCAPE),
            new LookupTranslator(EntityArrays.HTML40_EXTENDED_ESCAPE)));

    return buider.escape(s).toString();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I prefer to use `unbescape`, or something that also supports HTML5 entities